# Auto-generated view maintenance dialog is corrupt

Tags: database, view, sap-basis

I've created 3 tables, and 3 corresponding views, then I've generated a maintenance dialog in SE11 Utilities > Table Maintenance Generator for each of these views using the following settings:

[image]

The message "Request completed successfully" appears but the generated dialogs are unusable and seem corrupt. This is how it looks in screen painter:

[image]

When I've tried activating a cluster view on these 3 views I got the following error:

> Error while modifying dynpro SAPLZ...
>
> Message no. SV597
>
> Diagnosis
>
> The flow logic of the screen SAPLZMM01_FUNCGRP
> 0001 is not that of a generated view maintenance list screen. Either
> the screen has been considerably modified manually, or the view which
> it is based on has no maintainable key.
>
> System Response
>
> The screen has not been modified.
>
> Procedure
>
> Make the view cluster maintenance screen modifications required
> manually on the screen. See the transaction 'Generate table
> maintenance dialog' application help for the modifications required.

Edit: I followed [note 2178069](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2178069), it didn't help.

Please help. How to delete this dialog entirely and regenerate it correctly ?

Steps to reproduce the problem:

**1. Create a new table ZTEST**

- Delivery class: C

**2. Add three fields to the new table:**

- MANDT of data element MANDT
- CONFIG of type CHAR and LENGTH 12
- LIFNR of data element LIFNR

Check "key field" and "mandatory" for the first two fields.

[image]

**3. Click on "technical settings", give the following parameters:**

- Delivery class: APPL0
- Size category: 0

**4. Click Extras > Enhancement category**

- Pick the second option: "numeric / alphanumeric enhancement".

**5. Activate**

**6. Create a view based on this table.**

**7. In the fields tab, click Table Fields and copy all the fields (only the keys are present by default).**

**8. Put maintenance flag 'S' on the two key fields.**

[image]

**Important:** if the maintenance flags 'S' are removed from the view fields, the dialog is generated correctly. However, maintenance flags are needed for correct operation of the view cluster maintenance.

**9. Generate the maintenance dialog (Utilites > Table maintenance dialog):**

[image]

**10. Go to SM30, maintain your newly created view.**

[image]

If you enter a value and validate, the maintenance view will look like this:
[image]

A correct maintenance view should look like a table:
[image]

Comment: Do you have the same function group for the three tables? Maybe you can try to delete all three maintenance views (in SE11), than delete the function group (in SE37 or in SE80), than start again, to geenrate the maintenance views. If you have created the maintenace view for the first table, check in SM30 if it is working properly, before creating the next one.

Comment: I've tried that. First time with three separate function groups named as the views, then with a common function group named ZXX_FUNCGRP. It doesn't work properly from the first view.

Comment: (Deleting the views and re-creating them with different names didn't work either).

Comment: The 3 maintenance dialogs must not use the same screen (same number of same function group) ! Say ZMM01_CONFIGV uses overview screen 1, ZMM02 will use screen 2, ZMM03 will use screen 3.

Comment: NB: no need to try creating a view cluster if some of its view dialogs don't work.

Comment: @SandraRossi: they do use a different screen.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as it's currently impossible to tell you what is wrong without the details.

Comment: @SandraRossi: ok I've edited my post. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: @Cutter, I\d rather stick to approach offered by Jozsef: delete all objects, and recreate view by view from scratch. Do NOT create the second view in the same FG until you get to fully work the first one, do NOT edit maint.flag manually ever (`I put maintenance flag 'S' on the two key fields`) if you do not understand what you are doing, do NOT set enh.category for view/table until it's working without it, the conflicting cat. can break the generation. And finally do not create the view manually (`Create a view based on this table.`), the SM30 will make it all

Comment: @Suncatcher: If I don't set the maintenance flag 'S', the dialogs are generated correctly, but these flags are needed for correct operation of the maintenance dialog of the view cluster.

Comment: @Suncatcher: if I let SM30 create the view I would have only the key fields by default. I have to add these manually.

Comment: I've tried again with a new table, where I didn't set the enhancement category, and the maintenance dialog is still incorrect.

Comment: give the structure of all 3 tables

Comment: I can't reproduce with one table, the screen is not like yours, it shows at the same time both the "S" field at the top and below is a table control with the other columns. I guess you should look for patches at SAP Support or report a bug.

Comment: NB: in the maintenance view, you should not select the client column (`MANDT`) as type `S`, it's non sense: the user must not select a different client than the login client.

Comment: @SandraRossi: I've solved it by setting maintenance field 'S' on all fields of the primary key **minus one** (and ignoring the client), instead of all the fields of the primary keys (as described here: https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=473962134)
Then the view cluster is activated correctly and the independent views are modified to work as a hierarchy.
I'm curious: how did you set the 'S' flags in your test view ?

Comment: Oops I didn't pay attention to that. In my test, I checked only a few key fields, not all. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the 'S' flags were set incorrectly in the table views (SE11). They have to be set only for fields that exist in a parent view. The header view shouldn't have any 'S' fields because no parent view exists. The second view in the hierarchy should have 'S' fields set on **key of fields eixsting in the parent view** at most (and so on for lower views in the hierarchy) and never on the client field if there is one. If set correctly, the view cluster activation will modify the independant views to make them useable in a hierarchy.

See here: https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=473962134